# Round large non-decimal numbers, up and down with php

Tags: php

### How do I round larger numbers in php.

NOTE: I have aready tried the round function and can not seem to get it to work as i need

#### for example:

Say i have 4 listing in a database and they have 4 different prices.

```
    1st Price = 5,783

    2nd Price = 19,647

    3rd Price = 12,867

    4th Price = 23,647
```

Now we determin that the **lowest price** in the databae would be **5,783**

and the **highest price** is **23,647**.

now what i want to do is round down the lowest price to say the nearest **500** or **1000** or even **5000**

**example of nearset 1000**

lowest price **5,783** rounded down = **5000**

highest price **23,647** rounded up = **24000**

Comment: Try typing your question into google before asking it here. Typing "php round large numbers" into google returns the php round function as the top result.

Comment: i have done this, i have tried the round function, i have research php manual and couldnt seem to get it right, this is actuall my last resort.

Comment: @Wesley: Please accept the correct answer below instead of pasting that literally into your question. That's how this site works. Thank you! (and I removed it from your question).

Comment: @hakre, well the solution at the bottom is slighty different, to what the actual solution was for my question, so basicall you have just removed the solution, and i can not select correct answer as i am new member, thats how this site works. the only way i could show solution was to repost in my question, or answer my own question with an updated version of emil solution....hope this makes sense... so it would be good if you can put the solution back or put it in emil solution.

Comment: @hakre, i just had to check but it actually suggests that i updated my post rather than answering my own question with the updated solution. i realise you have a great rep on here, but either im missing something (which is quite possible) or you have missed judge you actions??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function nearest($num, $divisor) {
  $diff = $num % $divisor;
  if ($diff == 0)
    return $num;
  elseif ($diff >= ceil($divisor / 2))
    return $num - $diff + $divisor;
  else
    return $num - $diff;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
nearest(23647, 5000);
```

Similar functions, but when you want to decide for yourself in which direction to round:

```
function roundUp($num, $divisor) {
  $diff = $num % $divisor;
  if ($diff == 0)
    return $num;
  else
    return $num - $diff + $divisor;
}


function roundDown($num, $divisor) {
  $diff = $num % $divisor;
  return $num - $diff;
}
```

Comment: This is so close, near perfect, but i need to be able to say round up or round down like so: round_up(23647, 5000); round_down(23647, 5000);
could you help with this :)

Comment: The `elseif` and `else` part checks for that. Just change them to a single `else` block. Rounding down is done by `$num - $diff` and up by `$num - $diff + $divisor`

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution, a great help. would it be posible for you to update your solution as you said in your comment :) just that i tried to update it in my question, but got removed and have no way of showing full solution for other people that may need it, i cant answer my own question and i cant check your solution as being correct yet as i need a rep of 15 and i am i new member. i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: This function breaks for numbers greater than 9 digits

Comment: @Tom Do you have an example? Would love to fix my answer!

Comment: @EmilVikström just test with any number ten digits or more for the `$num` variable. Example: `echo nearest(347538334, 5000);` returns `347540000` but `echo nearest(3475383345, 5000);` returns `3475387296`

Comment: @Tom The reason is that you are on a 32-bit platform. Your number is larger than PHP_INT_MAX so you are really working on a `float` type value. My functions are only valid for integers.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the round in the [php manual](http://php.net/function.round.php). The fist example says:

```
<?php
    echo round(3.4);         // 3
    echo round(3.5);         // 4
    echo round(3.6);         // 4
    echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
    echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
    echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
    echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
    echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

I think you are looking for

```
round(23647, -3)
```

I've not checked this but it shold work (see manual).

If you want to kill the ',' you can use [number_format](http://php.net/function.number-format.php)

Comment: round(23647, -3) this works to round up to cloest thousand, how would we do this down to the closest thousand, also how would we do this for the closest 500 or 5000. i have had a little mess about trying to do this and can not seem to crack it.

Comment: PHPs builtin `round` does just round to multiples of 10.